# Playing Xbox on a Non-HD TV

Tags: xbox-one

My friend is planning to buy an Xbox one but he and i think that it will not work in his Non-HD TV. The main question is that can he play Xbox one on his Non-hd TV?

He don't remember his LG TV model but he has some written things such as that it is flatron, Ballad 2000, XD Picture( Whatever all these things mean)

Comment: Your friend is planning on buying an Xbox One? Not an original Xbox, correct?

Comment: Yeah, Xbox one.

Comment: Even if you get it to work, you'll probably have a lot of difficulty with text and other fine details that will be completely lost without a high definition screen.

Comment: You can always use a PC screen to use the Xbox One on, as long as it has an HDMI port. Should be more affordable and transportable than a new TV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends heavily on the features of the TV.  The Xbox One only supports HDMI out, and some features (like BluRay playback) require HDCP support as well.  However, it apparently [supports sub-720p resolutions](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/console/tv-resolutions), so slightly older TVs that are technically not "HD" may still work.

It's possible to convert the Xbox One's HDMI to a signal/connector format understood by an older TV, but the expense of buying a converter and playing at a much lower resolution is probably worse than just buying a cheap, small, HDMI/HDCP compliant TV.

Comment: Please read the edit and answer to that

Comment: @DeMize, random words on the front of the TV don't really help.  Does it have HDMI ports?  Can you find the model number somewhere on the back/side of the unit?  I'm going to guess that this TV isn't Xbox One compatible, just based on what you've said so far.